# Phishing login form

Tags: security, wget, phishing

I am working on a phishing quest, where I have to clone a company login form and test my colleagues who failed the cyber training.
My planning procedure is the following:

1. Get clone of (any) login form without any aditional tool like SET

   ```
   $ wget --mirror --convert-links --page-requisites https://somerandomloginform
   ```
2. Put "malicous" code into cloned code
3. Deploy it on my VPS and start testing

I'am stuck in the first step, because I thought that `--convert-links` will download not only the HTML page, but also all related js files, but it's not happened.
So maybe I didn't understand it correcly. Take for example Gmail login form, is it even possible to do it with simple command without tools like SET. And also because I am a web developer, I wonder if is there any protection against that?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The easiest way is by CTRL + S or more complicated with web scraping.

Answer (score -1):

> is it even possible to do it with simple command without tools like
> SET

It depends, `wget` is unable to execute JavaScript, so if resource is retrieved that way you would not get it.

> I am a web developer

Masquerading as login page of another site is [click-jacking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Types_of_attacks#click-jacking).

> any protection against

For possible protections against this and other types of attack you might consult OWASP cheat sheets, in this particular case [Clickjacking Defense Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet.html)